# passar valor para variavel php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tenho este código:

```
var $login = $("input[name='usuario']");

var dadosajax = {
    'cod': elemento.value,
    'login': $login.val(),
};

pageurl = 'salvar_dados_usuarios.php';

$.ajax({
    //url da pagina
    url: pageurl,
    //parametros a passar
    data: dadosajax,
    //tipo: POST ou GET
    type: 'GET',
    //cache
    cache: false,
    //se ocorrer um erro na chamada ajax, retorna este alerta
    //possiveis erros: pagina nao existe, erro de codigo na pagina, falha de comunicacao/internet, etc etc etc
    error: function () {
        alert('Erro: Ao Gravar Registo!!');
    },
    //retorna o resultado da pagina para onde enviamos os dados
    success: function (result) {    
        var valorRetornado = result
        // convertendo a string em objeto

        if (valorRetornado == 1) {
            alert('alterado');

            document.getElementById('sucesso').val('Alterado com sucesso!');
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.display = 'block';
        } else if (valorRetornado == 0) {
            alert('gravado');
            document.getElementById('sucesso').val('Gravado com sucesso!');
            document.getElementById('sucesso').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
});
```

e na pagina salvar_dados_usuarios.php, tenho isto:

```
require_once 'init.php';
$odb = db_connect();

$vl_login= $_REQUEST['login'];
$vl_id = $_REQUEST['cod'];

$sql_proc = "select * from users where usuario=trim($vl_login)";

// so funciona se o select for assim:
//"select * from users where usuario='robson'";

$data_proc = $odb->prepare($sql_proc);
$data_proc->execute();

$data = $data_proc->fetchAll();

if($data){
      echo '1' ;
}else {
    echo '0' ;
}
```

Ao executar a pagina, retorna sempre 1. Só funciona se retirar o `$vl_login` e digitar o nome do usuario. Preciso que funcione com valor do `$vl_login`.
Estou usando PDO e mysql.

Comment: Quando se usa string em query, tem que possuir apóstrofos: `"... usuario=trim('$vl_login')"`

Comment: Opa... era isso mesmo... agradeço. deu certo